# How can I solve this initial value problem?

Tags: initial-value-problems

I need to solve this question:

> Consider the IVP y' = f(x, y), for f(x, y) = x sin(y) and y(0) = π/2
>   for x ∈ [0, 3] =: I.
>
> Verify that $y(x) = π − arctan ( 2 e^{( x^ 2/ 2 )}/{e^{(x^2)}-1)}$  solves the IVP

Here is what I have so far:

Integrating on both sides, I get:

$ln|tan(y/2)| = {x^2 /2} + C$

$tan(y/2) = e^{x^2} + C$

inserting x=pi/2 and y=0 gives us, C=0

$y = (1/2)arctan(e^{x^2} )$

I don't know how to proceed further How can I get to $y(x) = π − arctan ( 2 e^{( x^ 2/ 2 )}/e^{(x^2)}-1)$

Comment: If you just want to verify the solution, then you can just take the derivative of the given function, you don't have to solve the DE from scratch.

Comment: Same as @dbx. But in case of curiosity, this is related to $$\tan2x=\frac{2\tan x}{1-\tan^2x}$$

Comment: I tried doing that too, but it isn't working. Is there an easier way?